# Creating custom visibility converter

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to create a custom converter for my MvvmCross project. I'm inheriting from MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter and just implementing the Convert method.

Do I need to implement platform specific projects as well or is there a way to reuse the platform specific visibility plugins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been documenting ValueConverters in the last few days - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters

I've just added this example custom visibility ValueConverter to the article:

---

If you need to create your own Visibility ValueConverter's then the `MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter<T>` and `MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter` base classes can assist with this - e.g.:

```
public class SayPleaseVisibilityValueConverter : MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter<string>
{
    protected override MvxVisibility Convert(string value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value == "Please) ? MvxVisibility.Visible : MvxVisibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

---

Using this approach, then the plugin base class will convert the `MvxVisibility` to a suitable native value at runtime - so **you only need to add this type of class to your core PCL project** - you don't need to add native versions of the class - instead the base class from the plugin will take care of the `MvxVisibility -> native Visibility` conversion.

---

Aside> in addition to the `Visibility` enum support from the Plugin, recent 'Tibet' binding changes have also added custom `Visible` binding properties to all platforms - these are just `bool`s so much easier to use - they should 'just work' on iOS and Android, but on Windows platforms they will only work if you switch to the "Tibet' `mvx:Bi.nd` style of binding (so not everyone's preferred approach!)

Comment: I read that document just before trying it out, I had my own plugin and figured I'll convert it to a simple one that just inherits. I guess the bootstrap in the UI projects was breaking it